# JS Global and Local Variables

Tags: javascript, variables, scope

I have been struggling trying to get some code to work and I think its due to my variable scopes. Instead of posting all my code here, I just made a simplified version to ask "why doesn't this work":

```
$(document).ready(function() {

console.log("INITIALIZE");
var aGlobalVariable = 25;

function testFunction(){

    var aLocalVariable = 5;

    var sumVariables = aGlobalVariable + aLocalVariable;

    console.log(sumVariables);
}

});
```

I would expect the testFunction to be able to see aGlobalVariable, add 25 to 5, and output 30. it doesn't do this. I can't even see the global variable if I try to do a console.log of it:

[image]

Is a variable declared at the start of a document not a global one????

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That isn't a global variable. Define it outside of the `ready` function.

```
var aGlobalVariable = 25;

$(document).ready(function() {

    console.log("INITIALIZE");


    function testFunction(){

        var aLocalVariable = 5;

        var sumVariables = aGlobalVariable + aLocalVariable;

        console.log(sumVariables);
   }

});
```

Now you should be able to see it work.

Answer (score 2):

`aGlobalVariable` is indeed known inside testFunction. Make a call to that function and check out the console:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    console.log("INITIALIZE");
    var aGlobalVariable = 25;

    function testFunction() {

        var aLocalVariable = 5;  
        var sumVariables = aGlobalVariable + aLocalVariable;

        console.log(sumVariables);
    }

    testFunction();
});
```

Here's a jsfiddle showing this:
https://jsfiddle.net/0c8rpLmj/

`aGlobalVariable` is undefined when you try to view it via the console since it's not in fact global (you have defined it under the ready function scope).

Answer (score 0):

Function expressions create variable scopes too.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var aGlobalVariable = 25;
```

Your variable is inside a function and declared with `var` so it isn't a global.

Move it outside the function expression if you want to make it a global.

```
var aGlobalVariable = 25;
$(document).ready(function() {
```

That said, making it a global probably isn't a good idea. Keeping it inside a local scope, but accessible to all the functions in that scope, means you have less change of other scripts interfering with your variable.